# input value to JSON angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Trying to do small function, when JSON is passed in input field, it just show the JSON in proper format.
**JS**

```
            function syntaxHighlight(json) {
            json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
            return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
                var cls = 'number';
                if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                    if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                        cls = 'key';
                    } else {
                        cls = 'string';
                    }
                } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                    cls = 'boolean';
                } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                    cls = 'null';
                }
                return match ;
            });
        }
        var obj = { a: 1, 'b': 'foo', c: [false, 'false', null, 'null', { d: { e: 1.3e5, f: '1.3e5' } }] };
        var str = JSON.stringify(vm.formatJSON, undefined, 4);

        console.log(syntaxHighlight(str));
```

If pass 'obj' variable in JSON.stringify, it work fine, but as soon as replace with my input ng-model, its return as string with "".

**HTML**

```
                <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.frmFormatJSON()">
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label>Format JSON</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="{}" ng-model="vm.formatJSON">
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="formatJSON">
                        Look
                   </button>
                </div>
            </form>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

**Output**
looking for this output in return

[image]

Comment: You should use json.parse to get json format. JSON.Stringify()  converts object to string. and while you replace in ng-model probably it takes as string because you may convert with JSON.Stringify()

Comment: @Dipakchavda, I am lost, can you show in snippet?

Comment: how about use this for json pretty huh? angular.toJson(jsonObj, true);

Comment: @smithLee any snippet?